# Loading JQuery in web worker using require.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-worker

I'm trying to implement a worker module into my app. The app itself is using require.js to load all the pre-requesites. And this is where all the  issues with loading worker-module begin.

**index.html**

```
<script>
    var worker = new Worker('worker_module.js');
</script>
```

**worker-module.js**

```
importScripts('../vendor/require.min.js');

require(['../vendor/jquery.min'], function ($){
   console.log("Test")
});
```

This error pops up every time I load the page.

```
Error: importScripts failed for ../vendor/jquery.min at ./../vendor/jquery.min.js
```

Any ideas what may be wrong? Am I missing anything?

Comment: What do you want jQuery for? You cannot manipulate DOM in WebWorker.

Comment: Anyway, this is a JQuery question already asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10491448/607407

Comment: yes I know, I only needed the part that handles the ajax requests ... but I  have solved this by writing my own plugin for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838883/html-web-worker-and-jquery-ajax-call) may answer your question.

As far as I know, It's not possible to use jQuery in web-worker, since jQuery requires DOM access.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to `importScripts` JQuery directly you'll see that it's jQuery, not Require.js error:

```
TypeError: document is undefined
```

JQuery is meant to work with the main dom document, and there is no DOM API available in web workers. [You can't use native API to parse HTML string either.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33651405/607407)

I found a workaround, the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33944817/607407
Here's a demo with your code exactly: http://fel.8u.cz/workerrjs/main/